# How Embed windows control library to asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I've created a windows control that needs to run in a web page. I don't have any idea on how to fix this.. it replies "the control type was not specified or the specified value type could not be found". I have pasted a copy of .dll of my windows control on my web project. 
here is the code I've used.

```
 <object id="myName" classid="http:ACEBARCODE.dll#ACEBARCODE.ACEBARCODEGENERATOR" width="500px" height="200px" />
```

please help me. thanks in advance:)

btw I use I run it on Firefox... I try this on IE but still no show.

Comment: Is this a winforms or WPF UI control?  Those are fundamentally different technologies than ASP.NET, and you can't reuse them in a web environment.  ASP.NET supports its own type of reusable controls, which are analogous to controls for winforms/wpf, but implemented completely differently.

Answer (score 2):

It is fundamentally impossible to use a Windows control in a web page.

You need to rewrite it from scratch in HTML and Javascript.

Comment: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Place-Windows-Control-To-Web-Form.aspx see this

Comment: That will only work in IE, and only with low security settings.  Don't do it.